# how to enable/disable a submit button, only if two conditions are provided: checking input radio and filling input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button, form-submit

I have this form:

```
<form name="myform" method="post">
  <input class="class_x" type="radio" name="name_1" value="value_1" id="id_1"/><br/>
  <input class="class_x" type="radio" name="name_2" value="value_2" id="id_2"/><br/>
  <input class="class_x" type="radio" name="name_3" value="value_3" id="id_3"/><br/>
  <input onkeyup="checkFormsValidity();" id="input_id" type="text" name="input_name" value="" required/><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit_name" value="OK" class="submit_class" id="SubmitButton"/>
</form>
```

three input radios, one input text, and one input submit button.

According to the javascript code:

```
//ENABLE OR DISABLE SUBMIT BUTTON CODE ACCORDING TO INPUT RADIO
function checkIfValid() {
var current = $('input.class_x').filter(':checked');

  if (current.length > 1) {
    sbmtBtn.disabled = false;
  } else {
    sbmtBtn.disabled = true;
  }
};

//ENABLE OR DISABLE SUBMIT BUTTON CODE ACCORDING TO INPUT TEXT
checkFormsValidity = function(){
var myforms = document.forms["myform"];   
    if (myforms.checkValidity()) {
        sbmtBtn.disabled = false;
    } else {
        sbmtBtn.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

if any of these two conditions are provided the input submit button will be enabled.
BUT what I need is that the input **submit button ONLY enables if BOTH conditions are provided**. AND if **ANY of these conditions are changed back** THEN the submit button should disable back again.

I know this needs a **very strict** syntax.

According to the code I am providing, what changes need to be done in order to achieve this? 
Here is the JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/Suiberu/1n5gbooq/

thanks!

Comment: 2 condition means one `radio` button & one `text` field.Or both  2 only with `radio` button

Comment: 2 conditions mean: TWO radio button and ONE text. YES, so basically you dont need to change BOTH functions, I hope

Comment: Are you sure the radio should be like that, giving different names makes the use radio pointless. You may as well use checkbox, if not, please use same name for radio boxes.

Comment: check the Fiddle. both functions work separatedly, what I need is them to work together.
the radio should be like that, I dont want checkboxes, And they cannot use the same name because of design purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
 [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1n5gbooq/1/)

condition : select  with `2 radio button & one text input`.

I was remove the link `keyup event` in html added direct with javascript.
No need to separably validate the `input text`

```js
//SUBMIT BUTTON VARIABLE DECLARED
var sbmtBtn = document.getElementById("SubmitButton");
sbmtBtn.disabled = true; 

//INPUTS RADIO; CHECK OR UNCHECK
var prv;
var markIt = function(e) {
  if (prv === this && this.checked) {
    this.checked = false;
    prv = null; 
  } else {
    prv = this;
  }
  checkIfValid();
};
$(function() {
  $('input.class_x').on('click', markIt);
   $('input[type=text]').on('keyup', markIt);
});

//ENABLE OR DISABLE SUBMIT BUTTON CODE ACCORDING TO INPUT RADIO
function checkIfValid() {
  var current = $('input.class_x').filter(':checked');
 if ((current.length > 1) && ($('input[type=text]').val() != "")) {
    sbmtBtn.disabled = false;
  } else {
    sbmtBtn.disabled = true;
  }
};
```

```css
input[type='submit']:disabled{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myform" method="post">
  <input class="class_x" type="radio" name="name_1" value="value_1" id="id_1"/><br/>
  <input class="class_x" type="radio" name="name_2" value="value_2" id="id_2"/><br/>
  <input class="class_x" type="radio" name="name_3" value="value_3" id="id_3"/><br/>
  <input id="input_id" type="text" name="input_name" value="" required/><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit_name" value="OK" class="submit_class" id="SubmitButton"/>
</form>
```